# Are you allowed to substitute for imaginary numbers on a real integral?

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, substitution

So, lets assume I am give this integral:

$$\int_{a}^b f(x)\text{d}x$$

where $a,b,c\in\Bbb{R}$ and $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$

Are you allowed to make the following substitution?

> Substitute $x=ci$

That (in my mind) will make the integral come out to $$\int_{ia}^{ib} if(c)\text{d}c$$

I don't know if something like that is allowed? Is it?

Comment: This is a generalization.

Comment: In many situations, one evaluates integrals over the reals, particularly definite integrals, by taking a detour through the complex numbers.

Comment: Well, it's probably fairly uncommon that $f(ci) = i f(c)$; if $f(x) = x^2$ for example $f(ci) = -f(c)$.

Comment: The $i$ is from $dx = i dc$, not from $f(ci) = i f(c)$.

Comment: Well $f$ is defined on $\mathbb R$ so what in the world does $f(ci)$ mean?

Comment: There is a problem with the way you have posed the problem. You've given $c$ as a constant but then make a substitution $x = ci$. This doesn't make sense, since $x$ is a variable ranging from $a$ to $b$. Instead, take out the mention of $c$ at the beginning, and write $x = ui$ for some $u \in \mathbb R$. Then the new integrand would be $f(ui)i\ \textrm du$.